# problema para utilizar los string

Tags: android-studio

tengo este código que debe poner el texto en mi parte visual pero solo me muestra la dirección numérica del string mas no el texto, mi idea es que funcione mediante mi archivo string.xml para que no tenga problemas con una traducción a otro idioma. ese es el codigo completo  pero el uniuco error lo manda en el public String []list_title he buscado en google pero no me sale una solución para este error parece ser algo realmente basico que no logro encontrar por ello estoy pidiendo ayuda.

[image: descripcion]
    public class SlideAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public SlideAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

//Array de imagenes
public int[] list_images = {
        R.drawable.div,
        R.drawable.sum,
        R.drawable.menos,
        R.drawable.mult,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher_background
};


//titulo o algo mas



public String[] list_title={
        String.valueOf(R.string.paso1),
        "paso 2",
        "paso 3",
        "paso 4",
        "paso 5"
};



//lista de descripciones
public String[] list_description={

       ""+R.string.paso1s+"",
        ""+R.string.paso2s,
        "",
        "44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444",
        "555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555"
};

//lista de colores
public int[] list_color={

        R.color.Ventanasc,
        R.color.colorPrimaryDark,
        R.color.leer3,
        R.color.leer2,
        R.color.Ventanasc,


};

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list_title.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
    return view==(RelativeLayout)obj;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide,container,false);

    RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.slidelinearlayout);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.slideimg);
    TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slidetitle);
    TextView txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slidedescription);


    img.setImageResource(list_images[position]);
    txt1.setText(list_title[position]);
    txt2.setText(list_description[position]);
    relative.setBackgroundColor(list_color[position]);

    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
}
```

}

Comment: Añade el código completo de la actividad con la captura de pantalla no se puede valorar el código

Comment: ya añadí todo completo  espero aya solución para esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas cogiendo mal el valor de la string cambia esto:

```
public String[] list_title={
        String.valueOf(R.string.paso1),
        "paso 2",
        "paso 3",
        "paso 4",
        "paso 5"
};
```

por esto

```
public String[] list_title={
        getResources().getString(R.string.paso1),
        "paso 2",
        "paso 3",
        "paso 4",
        "paso 5"
};
```

Es posible que te pida el contexto para poder ejecutarlo si es así añadelo.

**Editado:**

Ahora que me dijo esta función no tiene mucho sentido debería ser así:

public String[] getListTitle(){
        String list_title[] = new String[] { 
             String.valueOf(R.string.paso1),"paso 2", "paso 3", "paso 4" };
        return list_title;
};

El error te estaba diciendo que la variable list_title no tiene valor, prueba esto debería funcionarte

Comment: si me pide el context pero me aparece este error :
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: en la corrección que me mandaste esta todo bien solo tuve que cambiar el:
String.valueOf(R.string.paso1) por el  getResources().getString(R.string.paso1) que me habías propuesto anteriormente muchas gracias.

Comment: Cierto con las prisas olvide añadirlo ^^

Comment: No hay problema me sirvio mucho gracias en verdad.